# Google Analytics statistics for one page on my website?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to display **Google Analytics report** of a **particular page** on **my website** ?
Is there any `code/script` which will help me to achieve this? 
Precisely, i want to show **TOTAL NUMBER OF VISITS & NUMBER OF UNIQUE VISTORS** of a specific page on my website. If there's any **other alternative** (of Google Analytics) to achieve this, please do suggest?

Comment: see http://www.embeddedanalytics.com  - we have widgets which will display metrics for a given page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already tracking for every page, you could set up a duplicate Google Analytics profile which excludes every page except the one you're interested in.

[More details here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034832?hl=en-GB).